# How to open owl ng datepicker via icon trigger

Tags: html, css, angular, datepicker

Right now I am using owl ng datepicker - as shown in the image(https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker). But it is opening on input field click. I want it to be opened on datepicker icon click in my input box.

[image]
here is the html code for the same.

```
 <input id="fromDate" 
            name="fromDate" 
            type="text"
            placeholder="From Date" 
            class="form-control"
            tooltip="From Date"
            delay="500" 
            triggers=""
            #fromDateToolTip="bs-tooltip"
            (mouseenter)="fromDateToolTip.show()"
            (mouseleave)="fromDateToolTip.hide()"
            [(ngModel)]="fromDatePicker"
            [owlDateTime]="dt1" 
            [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1"
            readonly="readonly"
            (ngModelChange)="dateFilter()"
            (keydown.backspace)="clear()">
        <owl-date-time
            [pickerType]="'calendar'"
            [startAt]="startAtFromDate" 
            [showSecondsTimer]="true"
            (afterPickerClosed)="setFromDateSelected($event,dt1)" 
            (afterPickerOpen)="fromDatePickerOpen()"
             #dt1>
        </owl-date-time>
```

Comment: Can you provide info about your code? like the html and ts?

Comment: @LeandroMatilla I've added the code for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `[owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2"` from input field and place it some where in icon field.

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
    <h2>Trigger Picker by a Icon</h2>
    <label class="example-input-wrapper">
        Date Time
        <input placeholder="Date Time:" [(ngModel)]="dateTime" [owlDateTime]="dt2">
        <span class="example-trigger" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </span>
        <owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>
    </label>

    <h4>Value From Picker: {{dateTime}}</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [owlDateTimeTrigger](https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker#properties-owl-date-time-trigger) property.
The date time picker that this trigger is associated with.

Try with this:

```
<input id="fromDate" placeholder="From Date" ... [owlDateTime]="dt1 [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1">

<span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>

<owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'" [startAt]="startAtFromDate [showSecondsTimer]="true" (afterPickerClosed)="setFromDateSelected($event,dt1)" (afterPickerOpen)="fromDatePickerOpen()" #dt1></owl-date-time>
```